# HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN when making requests using axios in electron app

Tags: electron, axios

I have an electron app that uses axios to make requests.  The requests are erroring within electron with code `HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN`.

The same request code runs fine outside of electron (i.e. running node test.js).  I have tried using http-parser-js as suggested in other questions but still have this issue.

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function getter() {
try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

getter();
```

```
{ Error: Parse Error
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:451:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:469:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:296:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:277:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:232:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:165:17)
  bytesParsed: 636,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',
  reason: 'Invalid header value char',
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I tried before I got this code working:

1. deleted node_modules directory
2. deleted package-lock.json
3. deleted npm cache

None of these resolved the issue.  I finally got this code working by removing, then adding back the headers used in the request.

Comment: what do you mean by removing and adding back the headers used in the request?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else run into the similar issue, yesterday I got an error in axios: `Parse Error: Invalid header value char`, and it works fine when I call it outside my app using postman.

At first, I thought it was caused by my environment configuration or node_modules package error. I tried to reinstall my packages and I tried to remove my environment configuration code line by line, but none of these works.

Finally, it took me half a day to find out that the latest version of axios which is **0.19.0** doesn't support a high version of node! I fixed it by simply downgrade my node version to **10.17.0**